Replace first occurrence of character in spark dataframe pyspark
I know , I am asking very basic question here , But is there any way to replace first occurrence of character within pyspark dataframe.
I have below value within dataframe.
Gourav#Joshi#Karnataka#US#English

I only want to replace first occurrence of # within dataframe.
Expected Output:
Gourav Joshi#Karnataka#US#English


Try these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71673030/spark-replace-first-occurrence-in-a-string

Just use regexp_replace and capture the sub-string before the 1st # as $1:
spark.sql("""
    select col, regexp_replace(col,'^([^#]*)#','$1 ') col_new
    from values ('Gourav#Joshi#Karnataka#US#English') as (col)
""").show(1,0)
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|col                              |col_new                          |
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|Gourav#Joshi#Karnataka#US#English|Gourav Joshi#Karnataka#US#English|
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+


You can use the split function to split the string into two parts based on the first #, and then use the array_join function to connect them.
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
...
df = df.select(F.array_join(F.split('col', '#', 2), ' '))


Try this:
ab=ab.withColumn("string1",split(col("string"),"#").getItem(0))
ab=ab.withColumn('new', split('string', '#'))\
      .withColumn("ok",slice(col("new"), 2, size(col("new"))))
ab=ab.withColumn("string2",concat_ws("#",col("ok"))).drop("ok","new")
ab.show(truncate=False)


I think the most feasible solution here is to use the regex_replace and repalce # with the space.
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, col 
df = df.withColumn("new_column", regexp_replace(col("initialcol"), r"#", " ", 1))


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
